# Understanding Dirac's argument for the indistinguishability of electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, orbitals, identical-particles

In his paper 'On the theory of quantum mechanics' (1926), Dirac makes the following argument for why electrons should be considered indistinguishable:

> Consider now a system that contains two or more similar particles, say, for definiteness, an atom with two electrons. Denote by $(mn)$ that state of the atom in which one electron is in an orbit labelled $m$, and the other in the orbit $n$. [...] The two transitions [$(mn)\to(m'n')$ and $(mn)\to(n'm')$] are, however, physically indistinguishable, and only the sum of the intensities for the two together could be determined experimentally.

I don't understand the final statement. The transition frequency $f_{mm'}=\frac{E_m-E_m'}{h}$ can be different from $f_{mn'}$ and similarly $f_{nn'}\neq f_{nm'}$, so the two transitions give separate pairs of spectral lines, whose intensities can be measured separately. What am I missing here?

Comment: But how would you know *which* electron is in state $m$? the only thing is knowable is that *an* electron is in state $m$ and an *other* electron is in state $n$. Electrons are waves not tiny billiard balls with numbers on them.

Comment: It looks more like Dirac is explaining the *consequences* of indistinguishability of electrons, i.e., if you assume that electrons are not distinguishable from each other, it follows that those two indicated transitions are also not distinguishable from each other.

Comment: @BrianBi
I disagree. Dirac starts the section by stating that Heisenberg's matrix mechanics 'gives no information about quantities [...] that one can never hope to measurement experimentally' and that 'we should expect this very satisfactory characteristic to persist in all future developments of the theory'. After presenting the argument as quoted in my question, he then concludes that 'hence, in order to keep the essential characteristic of the theory that it shall enable one to calculate only observable quantities, one must adopt [...] that (mn) and (nm) count as only one state'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to $f_{mm'}$, $f_{nn'}$, etc. separately.  All you have is the frequency of the photons which have the *total* amount of energy emitted/absorbed in the transition.  And
$$
\Delta E_{m \to m'} + \Delta E_{n \to n'} = (E_{m'} - E_m) + (E_{n'} - E_n) = (E_{n'} - E_m) + (E_{m'} - E_n) \\= \Delta E_{m \to n'} + \Delta E_{n \to m'}.
$$

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!